# How to connect to an imap connector from a windows service using OAuth2

Tags: exchange-basicauth

We have a windows service that collects mail from via an imap connector and then processes that email and attachments into a database.  Is there a way that we can do this using OAuth2 when exchange online removes support for basic authentication?  There is no user interface to the service or user access to teh system when it is running beyond the start and stop of the service.
We are currently using Chilkat's excellent Imap component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft have finally released support and documentation for this in Exchange Online. See the following Microsoft document:

[Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)